# Combine Pie Chart Values but not its Legend values

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, legend

Using matplotlib & python3, I've generated a Pie chart & combined all its values less than 2%.
The problem is its Legend box is also combining all the values less than 2%.

I want the Legend to retain all its values, without combining anything at all.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of the legend to describe what each of the colours in the pie chart refer to? Maybe that information shouldn't be in the legend but elsewhere?

Comment: True, it is the purpose; but my current requirement demands so...

Comment: how is your legend current set up? Is it just color: label? or color: label, value

Comment: Its the second one:-Color: Label, Value